# I can't type a “b” when I'm in the command line

Tags: 14.04, keyboard, ssh

#### Update

I can't even paste a `b`. I am trying to upgrade to Ubuntu 15.04 but I need to delete some files in the /boot directory. When I `cd /oot` I can't type a `b`. So, I thought, I will list the files in the `/` directory and copy/paste, but to no avail. I can't even paste a `b`.

#### Update 2

I recently added some lines to the `/etc/inputrc` file in order to get better tab auto-completion:

```
set completion-ignore-case on
set show-all-if-ambiguous on
TAB: menu-complete
bind TAB:menu-complete
```

---

#### Original Question

When I ssh into my ubuntu server I can't type the letter "b". I can however type a capital "B" using either shift keys.

I'm using a MacBook Pro with Retina display from 2012, and I'm ssh-ing into a custom built ubuntu box. It is here that I can't type a lower case "b".

I have restarted the server and yet I still can't type a "b". Every other letter is fine.

It hasn't done that before, I've had the server up and running for about two years and haven't come across an issue like this before. I also haven't done anything notable to cause it to do that.

At first I thought the keyboard was a little sticky but when I closed the connection it works fine. I've restarted the server, ssh'd back in and the "b" key stops working again.

I've tried my bluetooth keyboard and still no luck.

Could this be something that is a rule in a .profile or .bashrc file or something similar? A setting to not allow certain characters.

When I try to type the letter "b" I get the terminal bell sound as if it is not allowed.

Comment: Does it work when not using ssh?

Comment: Yes, absolutely fine. At first I thought the keyboard was a little sticky but when I closed the connection it works fine. I've restarted the server, ssh'd back in and the b key stops working again.

Comment: It hasn't done that before, I've had the server up and running for about two years and haven't come across an issue like this before. I also haven't done anything notable to cause it to do that.

Comment: Please add this to your question using the [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/616525/edit) button under your post.

Comment: I don't think it is that as it is fine everywhere else. It's a MacBook Pro so I doubt it is a fault like that. It is too consistent to only occur in this state that I am sure it is something else.

Comment: Not in `.profile` or `.bashrc`, but probably in `.inputrc` or `/etc/inputrc` (readline's config file) it could be a lone `b` letter on its own row.

Comment: @egmont can you write that as an answer. I had recently edited that file to allow for tab-completion and I've since removed those four lines and the "b" works again now. The offending lines are below. Do you happen to know what it _should_ be?

set completion-ignore-case on
set show-all-if-ambiguous on
TAB: menu-complete
bind TAB:menu-complete

Comment: It's hard to read the file's contents without proper formatting. Maybe you should ask a brand new question, including stating your goals. I've never touched tab completion, I'm happy with what Ubuntu offers me with the "bash-completion" package. The two "set" lines look good. My wild guess is that the keyword "TAB" is not the proper token and you'd need "\t" or something similar. Maybe the word "bind" causes it to handle "b" differently, it waits to see if you follow by typing "ind" next, it's probably not a proper keywoard in this context.

Comment: I'll update my question with those lines that I added, and if you update your answer to say to remove them then I can award you the 50 rep.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Inside the ssh session, start a `cat` command and see whether you can type `b` there. I'm almost sure it'll work, which means that it's your shell that decides not to act on `b`.

Assuming the default `bash`, you should check `readline`'s configuration files: `~/.inputrc`, `/etc/inputrc`, or the one referred by `$INPUTRC`. Chances are you'll find an accidental lone `b` on its own line (or something similar), instructing readline not to do anything upon encountering this character.

Update

Looks to me that the first three lines of your `.inputrc` are correct, it's the fourth line (`bind TAB:menu-complete`) causing the trouble. Change its first letter to anything else (e.g. `find` instead of `bind`) and then that letter (e.g. `f`) will misbehave. Apparently `bind` is not a recognized keyword in this context.

Comment: I have to wait 24 hours to award the bounty. I will do it then. Thank you.

Comment: could OP just leave it as `TAB:menu-complete` ?

Comment: You are correct, `TAB:menu-complete` works

Answer (score 1):

```sh
TAB: menu-complete
bind TAB:menu-complete
```

Should just be

```sh
TAB:menu-complete
```