# Lowercase 's' doesn't work in Ubuntu terminal

Tags: gnome-terminal, xterm

Anyone else had this very infuriating problem that has been bugging me for the past hour. The lowercase 's' and only that key alone doesn't ever get printed on my terminal or xterm. Every other key works fine and the 's' key words fine in any other application but not in terminal. Googling just says a custom keyboard shortcut has been set to s but looking at all the keyboard shortcuts in System -> Keyboard -> Custom Shortcuts shows no such shortcut and I cleared the few that had 's' in it. Rebooting etc. didn't help. Another interesting thing is that if I press Ctrl + Shift + V which was the key for paste then it lets me type 's' but after that I can't enter s anymore. I have used gconf-editor and dconf-editor and have reset all CCSM settings and restarted unit, but nothing is working.

I tried installing other terminal emulators, but the same problem exists. With more investigation I found out that the problem occurs only in a bash shell. If I run csh the issue doesn't happen. So something happened that remapped the bash keys. Also along with Ctrl + Shift + V if I press Ctrl + V it lets me type s once in bash.

Comment: Try installing another terminal emulator such as Guake or Konsole. If there is a problem there, you know it is likely a system wide issue. If it does not, then there is only a problem with the default terminal. Other terminal emulators
http://www.tuxarena.com/intro/ref_term.php

Comment: I tried installing other terminal emulators but the same problem exists. With more investigation I found out that the problem occurs only in a bash shell. If I run csh the issue doesn't happen. So something happened that remapped the bash keys. Also along with Ctrl + Shift + V if I press Ctrl + V it lets me type s once in bash.

Comment: How many keyboard layouts are active in your system? Is this in your laptop? How long have you owned this laptop?

Comment: I have only one keyboard layout active. @JonasCz It is exactly this problem but I don't see anything in my .inputrc files. It happened after I pressed a combination of Ctrl + Alt + Shift + S key which was a custom shortcut to start my wifi. I probably pressed  a wrong combo doing some wierd mapping of s but I am unable to figure out how to rectify it

Answer (score 1):

It was a duplicate of [I can't type a “b” when I'm in the command line](https://askubuntu.com/questions/616525/i-cant-type-a-b-when-im-in-the-command-line). I had added this line in my /etc/inputrc
"stty ....." . That was making 's' misbehave.

Comment: Then, instead of posting and answer, this question should be closed by you as a duplicate of the linked question.