# "show-all-if-amset" spam in terminal when pressing "b" key once

Tags: bash, gnome-terminal

I am new to ubuntu and when I recently tried to execute a command in the terminal and pushed the "b" key , it typed "set" and then started to spam "show-all-if-amset".

[image]

How can I solve this?

Edit: On second look,it just types "set show-all-if-am", still don't know what it means though...

Edit 2: This happens in the visual code terminal as well.

Edit 3: This seems to be a problem with bash, the same issue doesn't happen with dash or sh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The input you type for example in a terminal is evaluated by a tool called [Readline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Readline). Readline has a few dozens variables that can be set to customize its behaviour. One of those variables is `show-all-if-ambiguous`. The syntax to change the value of `show-all-if-ambiguous` or another Readline variable would be

```
set show-all-if-ambiguous on
```

or

```
set show-all-if-ambiguous off
```

respectively. Those settings are meant to go into a config file called `.inputrc` (note the dot at the start) in your user's home directory.

It looks like a Readline setting was put somewhere where it doesn't belong, and it throws a wrench into things. Maybe you put it somewhere yourself, or a program / tool / script / ... you're using is buggy or not correctly installed.

If you can get a terminal to behave enough to do it, a search for "set show-all-if-ambiguous" over your home directory might get you on the track of the "culprit":

```
grep -rIl 'set show-all-if-ambiguous' /home/yourusername
```

You need to replace "yourusername" with your user name, obviously ;)

Comment: You are right, i put this line in the .inputrc earlier.
 If I comment it out though, when i press "b" nothing happens

```
$include /etc/inputrc
set completion-ignore-case On

bind TAB:menu-complete
bind "set show-all-if-ambiguous on"
```

Comment: I can't even paste "b" in the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, in the .inputrc file I had the following lines:

```
$include /etc/inputrc 
set completion-ignore-case On 
bind TAB:menu-complete 
bind "set show-all-if-ambiguous on
```

I don't know why this worked before, but apparently, as specified in this post: [I can't type a “b” when I'm in the command line](https://askubuntu.com/questions/616525/i-cant-type-a-b-when-im-in-the-command-line),
 the word "bind" is not recognised. Removing the bind solved the problem.

Many thanks to Henning Kokerbeck for telling me the problem was with the .inputrc file!