# Why does the terminal not let me type the letter r (Lowercase)

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal

The terminal does not let me type the letter R (Lowercase r). Why is this. I am fine with sending you files but not files that need sudo access because I do not have sudo and I don't have the super user password.

Here's my /etc/inputrc file:

```sh
# /etc/inputrc - global inputrc for libreadline
# See readline(3readline) and `info rluserman' for more information.

# Be 8 bit clean.
set input-meta on
set output-meta on

# To allow the use of 8bit-characters like the german umlauts, uncomment
# the line below. However this makes the meta key not work as a meta key,
# which is annoying to those which don't need to type in 8-bit characters.

# set convert-meta off

# try to enable the application keypad when it is called.  Some systems
# need this to enable the arrow keys.
# set enable-keypad on

# see /usr/share/doc/bash/inputrc.arrows for other codes of arrow keys

# do not bell on tab-completion
# set bell-style none
# set bell-style visible

# some defaults / modifications for the emacs mode
$if mode=emacs

# allow the use of the Home/End keys
"\e[1~": beginning-of-line
"\e[4~": end-of-line

# allow the use of the Delete/Insert keys
"\e[3~": delete-char
"\e[2~": quoted-insert

# mappings for "page up" and "page down" to step to the beginning/end
# of the history
# "\e[5~": beginning-of-history
# "\e[6~": end-of-history

# alternate mappings for "page up" and "page down" to search the history
# "\e[5~": history-search-backward
# "\e[6~": history-search-forward

# mappings for Ctrl-left-arrow and Ctrl-right-arrow for word moving
"\e[1;5C": forward-word
"\e[1;5D": backward-word
"\e[5C": forward-word
"\e[5D": backward-word
"\e\e[C": forward-word
"\e\e[D": backward-word

$if term=rxvt
"\e[7~": beginning-of-line
"\e[8~": end-of-line
"\eOc": forward-word
"\eOd": backward-word
$endif

# for non RH/Debian xterm, can't hurt for RH/Debian xterm
# "\eOH": beginning-of-line
# "\eOF": end-of-line

# for freebsd console
# "\e[H": beginning-of-line
# "\e[F": end-of-line

$endif
```

Contents of `/etc/X11/xinit/xinputrc`:

```sh
# im-config(8) generated on Sun, 30 Mar 2014 02:45:02 +0900
run_im default
```

Comment: This is a very similar story: https://askubuntu.com/questions/616525/i-cant-type-a-b-when-im-in-the-command-line You can show us the file relevant in this story, because you do have read permission for it (you just cannot save any changes to it). Since it's a long-ish file, let's make it easier to copy its contents, by opening in a graphical text editor. You could try `gedit /etc/inputrc`.

Comment: Should I add it to my question because it is too long to send?

Comment: Yes, that should be fine.

Comment: I had never ever edited the file.

Comment: @Levente Is it possible that you can do something?

Comment: No, because in the other question, there was something easily identifiable in the file. But this file does not seem to contain any such easily identifiable problem. It's possible that the problem is caused by something in another file. But I don't know which.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/120142/discussion-between-johann-george-and-levente).

Comment: Please post the contents of `/etc/X11/xinit/xinputrc` too.

Comment: Also, if you run this in the terminal: `im-config --version` what does it say?

Comment: One more thing: `grep -i "im-config" /var/log/syslog` does it say anything that looks like some trouble?